# KNN distance function with one for loop

Tags: machine-learning, classification, knn

part of my assessment I'm writing the code for KNN classifier with one for loop, so I suppose to multiple each training examples with all of the testing examples, and this what I come up with:

```
for i in range(num_train):
    distance = (x_train[i].view(-1, 1) - x_test.view(-1, num_test))
    eucl_squ = distance**2
    sum = eucl_squ.sum(dim=0)
    dists[i] = sum
```

and it's not correct and the correct one is:

```
for i in range(num_train):
    dists[i]=torch.sum((x_test - x_train[i])**2,dim=1).t()
```

and I don't know why mine is not right.

Comment: *"and it's not correct and the correct one is:"* What do you mean?

Comment: I meant that the first solution which I wrote isn't correct, the second one is the correct one, and I can't see why.

Comment: How do you know it's not correct?

Comment: because it's part of the quiz, and when I write my solution it gave me an error